# True or False with Once SQL Command

Tags: sql, sql-update, sqlcommand, mysql

I want to run sql command only once for update column..

```
UPDATE article SET published = '1 OR 0' WHERE id = '1'
```

In above command "**1 OR 0**" is mean;

If article's published column is **1/true**, set **0/false**.. If published is **0/false**, set **1/true**..

What can i do?

Thanks for help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE article SET published = NOT published WHERE id = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `if()` function:

```
UPDATE article 
SET published = if(published=0,1,0) 
WHERE id = '1';
```